# What's the power of the following Hypothesis test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

This is a question I got on my recent intro-stats exam which I still can't comprehend.

"What's the power of a hypothesis test with significance level 0.05, if the probability of picking 5 or more things from a box of 15 is larger than 50% when the probability is actually 75%?"

I think you can interpret this in different ways, as it's ambiguous.

What do you think?

Comment: It would be a better question if it stated how things were picked and what the the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis were.  What different ways do you think it might intend to say?

Comment: Well I agree, but this particular professor likes to keep most details hidden and it easily turns into a guessing work. I think we can assume things are picked uniformly but it's never stated. 

I was thinking $H_0: p = 0.5$ and $H_1: p > 0.5$ and then approximate a normal distribution or something, but right now I've tried so many different things and am not sure of anything anymore. One thing I'm sure of is that I didn't write the correct answer.